# Telerik RadGrid Culture setting not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I was expecting that the property **Culture** of the radgrid can be used to set the culture of the grid and this reflect also the data displayed in its cells, right?

But in this Grid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="GrdWaypoints" runat="server" Width="550px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Culture="en-US"
                            AllowAutomaticUpdates="false" AllowAutomaticInserts="false"AllowAutomaticDeletes="false"
                             OnDeleteCommand="GrdWaypoints_DeleteCommand"OnInsertCommand="GrdWaypoints_InsertCommand" OnUpdateCommand="GrdWaypoints_UpdateCommand"OnItemDataBound="GrdWaypoints_ItemDataBound"
                            GroupPanelPosition="Top" OnNeedDataSource="GrdWaypoints_NeedDataSource">
     <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="false">
         <Scrolling AllowScroll="false" UseStaticHeaders="false" />
     </ClientSettings>
     <GroupingSettings ShowUnGroupButton="false" />
     <MasterTableView ShowGroupFooter="False" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="WaypointID"EditMode="InPlace">
        <Columns>
             <telerik:GridNumericColumn  UniqueName="Longitude" HeaderText="Longitudine"DataField="Longitude" DecimalDigits="6" DataFormatString="{0:#0.000#}" ></telerik:GridNumericColumn>
        </Columns>
     </MasterTableView>
     </telerik:RadGrid>
```

... no matter what I specify in the culture property, the numbers, in the longitude GridNumeric column, are always displayed based on the number format specified in the **regional settings** of the server.

And obviously, on the Insert and Update command, everything goes in error if the user types the number in a different culture from the server.

Does anyone know a workaround for this bug?

Comment: Have you tried setting the culture in the cs file?

Comment: Yes but it's ignored when the grid goes in edit mode and I have the GridNumericColumn. It seems it only works for loading the resource files

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?